# Equality question

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Hi I'm a bit confused with this?

$\frac{1}{x} < 0 \iff x\frac{1}{x} < x\times 0 =0 \iff 1 < 0$

This was another question that I saw which was $\frac{1}{x} < 0$ but when I multiplied by $x$ I got $1<0$?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I am not convinced by your use of $\iff$ here, as a you have a free variable in $\frac{1}{x} < 0$ but not in $ 1 < 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication by a negative number reverses inequalities.

Comment: The gist here being, if x is negative, the inequality needs to be reversed.